# can i use the swiftdata framework for an existing sqlite database?

Tags: ios, swift

i am developing an IOS application. i am using swift data framework for sqlite database. can i use the same swift data framework for an existing database?

I have been looking for the solution but couldn't find it. can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Ryan Fowler's [SwiftData.swift](https://github.com/ryanfowler/SwiftData) on GitHub, then it looks like there is some info about half-way down his documentation page: http://ryanfowler.github.io/SwiftData/

Perhaps info on this method is what you are looking for (regarding connecting to an existing db).

```
public static func databasePath() -> String
```

And keep in mind, SQLite databases are transactional. So, the framework probably just maintains a path pointer and then opens and closes the db as needed to make transactions:

```
public static func transaction(transactionClosure: ()->Bool) -> Int?
```